# Executing local (driver) code iteratively on Spark DataFrame items

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark, Dataframes and Python.

Let say I have a quite huge dataframe, with every Row containing some JPG images as binary data. I want to build some kind of browser to display every image sequentially.

I have a *view* function that take a single row as input and does something like this:

```
def view(row):
    windows = popup_window_that_display_image(row.image)
    waitKey()
    destroy_window(window)
```

The following code works fine with spark-submit option *--master local[*]*:

```
df = load_and_compute_dataframe(context, some_arguments)
df.foreach(view)
```

Obviously, the *view* function cannot run on remote Spark executors. So the above code fails in *yarn-client* mode.

I can use the following code to work in *yarn-client* mode:

```
df = load_and_compute_dataframe(context, some_arguments)
data = df.limit(10).collect(); 
for x in data:
    view(w)
```

The drawback is that I can only collect a few items. Data is too huge to get more than 10 or 100 items at once.

So my questions are:

- Is there a mean to have some DF/RDD operation executes locally on the driver, instead of the executors ?
- Is there something that allows me to collect 10 items from a DF, starting from the 11th ? Should I try to add an "ID" column to my DF and iterate over it (ugly) ?
- Any other way to achieve this result ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: The best thing you can do is to save your data to the system that supports random access (like your-favorite-database) and read it from there. It is possible to use `toLocalIterator`, `indexedRDD` or other tricks but there is no real value in using Spark for something like this.

Comment: Yes, I though of it. The issue is that load_and_compute_dataframe is quite data intensive (a few minutes on 200 cores), and this function changes a lot. I wanted to avoid having to export data out of HDFS to view this data.